# Cant include json-simple-1.1.1.jar

Tags: java, json-simple

I try compile following code (file Main.java):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Main {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
      obj.put("name", "foo");
      obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
      obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
      obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));
      System.out.print(obj);
   }
}
```

json-simple also included (stored at ./lib/)

```
javac Main.java
java -cp .:lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar Main
```

And i got:

```
error: package org.json.simple does not exist
cannot find symbol JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
```

What i doing wrong?

P.s. i'm using:

Ubuntu 14.04

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)

I'm not using any IDE

**Update:**

Current directory:

```
/home/user/helloworld/
```

json-simple placed to directory:

```
/home/user/helloworld/lib/
```

Comment: So, what's in the current directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give `javac` the classpath so it can compile the Java source into class files.

Use:

```
javac -cp .:lib/json-simple-1.1.1.jar Main.java
```

Note that you still need to supply the `json-simple` jar on the classpath when you run it too (i.e. like you have been doing).